# Serialize nested objects with jackson

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, jackson

I want to have an output like

```
   { Orga1: [ dep1, dep2], Orga2: [dep88, dep99], ...}
```

but somehow I fail to get it properly done.

I have the following structure:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = OrganisationSerializer.class)
public class Organisation {
    String name;

    private HashMap<String, Department> lstDepartments = new HashMap<>();

    public List<Department> getList() {
        return lstDepartments.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

with the nested class

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DepartmentSerializer.class)
public class Department {
    String name;

    HashMap<String, Role4Filter> lstRole = new HashMap<>();

    public List<Role4Filter> getList() {
        return lstRole.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
...
}
```

The major problem is that the `HashMap` needs to be transferred into a `List` which needs to be serialized. But somehow I fail to convert into a JSON properly.

My approach with

```
public class OrganisationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Organisation> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Organisation value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeArrayFieldStart(value.name);
    for (final Department item : value.getList()) {
        gen.writeObject(item);
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

fails with the exception that

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: org..Department cannot be cast to org..Organisation
```

Any ideas? Or is there some other annotation possible (beside the serializer?)

Comment: It is not clear what do you expect. Could you create example `POJO` representation and how it should look like after serialisation?

Comment: as mention in the intro. An object with a nested simple list of names. Just plain Strings (=`name`). But somehow I have no clue how to transfer the Hashmap into a single `ArrayList` which will be finally serialized.

Comment: You have two `POJO` classes: `Organisation` and `Department` and you have a casting problem: "org..Department cannot be cast to org..Organisation". So, we need to see an example hod do you serialise these `POJO` classes. Could you create simple app which shows the problem, right now it is not clear where exactly it appears.

Comment: Hmm... The exception occurs in the `OrganisationSerializer` at `gen.writeObject(item)`